# Source of the Ganesha shloka, "Srikantho Mathulo Yasya"

Tags: ganesha, shloka

What is the source of the Ganesha shloka, "Srikantho Mathulo Yasya, Jananee Sarva Mangalaa, Janakaha Sankaro Devaha, Tam Vande' Kunjaraananam"?

श्रीकान्तो मातुलो यस्य​
जननी सर्वमंगला।
जनकः शंकरो देवः
तम् वन्दे कुंजराननम्॥﻿

Meaning of shloka: The Lord, for whom Lord Vishnu, the husband of Lakshmi is the uncle, whose mother is the all auspicious one, Parvati and whose father is Lord Shiva; I offer salutations to Sri Ganesha, the elephant faced.

Comment: Looks like this shloka is not part of any scripture , but its a invocation prayer of a book called " Sri Ramodantam"  by Parameshwara Kavi from Kerala.

Comment: Hi there, just went through the book; couldn't find the shloka.  I am from Kerala, Ulloor S. Parameswara Iyer is quite famous.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: http://pranavasagar.blogspot.com/2018/03/blog-post.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this sloka as the invocation sloka for the Navagraha Stotra, penned by Veda Vyaasa.  The link for Navagraha stotra itself is
https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_navagraha/navanew.html
I believe, the book where I found the sloka is a collection called Jaya Mangala Stotras (a compilation by the famous Late Sri AnantaRama Dishitar of Selam, Tamil Nadu; he brought a revival to stotram chanting as nobody else had done!  He was as great as the Bhattatri of Narayaniyam fame.